# Overwrite css class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a css class **pause**. This is applied in various pages. Only one section of
markup  doesn't **margin-left:42px;**, so I want to make it **0px**. I don't want to 
use a new class because I am applying this class dynamically using jQuery for
certain conditions.

So, I need to overwrite the class to make **margin-left:0px;** from markup.

css

```
.pause a{
         background-image:url(../img/pink_pause.png);float:left;
         height:26px;width:96px; margin-left:42px; margin-top:6px;
         }
```

markup

```
<td  class="pause  bid_button_logout bidder_name">
<a href="login"></a>
</td>
```

How can I neutralize margin-left by any other class or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't define another style, use an inline style on the element that you don't want `margin-left` applied to. Inline styles are more specific than those defined elsewhere, so it should take precedence:

`<a href="login" style="margin-left:0">`

Answer (score 1):

You could split the .pause into two css classes where one of them only defines the extra margin, and simply not apply that class to the ones that don't need margin.

Or set the style attribute on the element like this: `style="margin-left: 0;"`, this will override the css value.

Or you could create anoter class called say ".noMargin" like this:

```
.noMargin{ margin-left: 0 !important; } 
/* important overrides other class values 
   even if the cascading would not */
```

and apply that class to the ones you dont want to have the extra margin.

Comment: Typical when I've finished writing 3 ways of doing it, each method is already answered by several others... heheh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use inline style:

```
<a href="login" style="margin-left:0px;"></a>
```

Or creating a new declaration:

```
.bid_button_logout a{
    margin-left: 0px; 
}
```

but this has to come *after* `.pause a`.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you really need to switch classes see [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the important hack:

```
margin-left: 0px !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `bid_button_logout` or `bidder_name` are unique to the situation where you want no margin, add `margin-left:0px;` to either of those classes (but make sure they are after `.pause a` in your css file. If not, use your conditional jQuery to add an inline style, which will bypass the original left margin style.